# Telerik MVC Combobox - Change background of an item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, combobox, telerik-mvc

I tried to change the hightlight of an item, it worked using:

```
            var combobox = $('#ComboBox').data('tComboBox');
            combobox.highlight(2);
```

The problem is I can only highlight on item!!  Is there another way to change the background or font (bold) so the user can remember which item they have selected.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically to mark an item as selected all you need is to add the 't-state-selected' class to it.
So for example to make all the items in the dropdown area selected, you can get a reference like this to them and append the class:

```
$('#ComboID').data().tComboBox.dropDown.$items.addClass('t-state-selected');
```

Comment: Thanks, the name of my drop combobox is ComboID, I added your answer to on_load script, I have this item selected,     item.Add().Text("Item3").Value("3").Selected(true); I got this error:  Unable to get value of the property 'addClass': object is null or undefined.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that the $items will not be availble until you click to open the DropDownList - it is constructed on demand.
Fortunately you can force it to construct it with the fill method.

$('#ComboBox').data().tComboBox.fill()

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I added to on_load:     var combobox = $('#ComboBox').data('tComboBox').fill();
           $('#ComboBox').data().tComboBox.dropDown.$items.addClass('t-state-selected');  Got this error: Unable to get value of the property 'dropDown': object is null or undefined

Comment: I got it to work like that:  var combobox = $(this).data('tComboBox');
        combobox.dropDown.$items.addClass('test');
However the question is how can I change specific items for example 1 and 3.  Thanks

Comment: Use combobox.dropDown.$items.eq(0).addClass('test'); and 
combobox.dropDown.$items.eq(2).addClass('test'); Or cycle through the collection $items and append the class to the desired items.